matlab SVAR cumulative impulse response
While I replicate Killan(2009), I cannot understand some point.
With using well-made function, irf and error band has been made and I started to plot them.
But here, although "cumsum(-INF(:,1,1))" // "-cumsum(INF(:,1,1))" shows same values,
the plots using both method shows different shapes like the added picture.
enter image description here
What happen in the MATLAB?
Moreover, can you suggest an appropriate way to replicate that paper's figure 2 and figure3?
addpath(genpath('/Program Files/MATLAB/R2024a/VAR-Toolbox-main/VAR-Toolbox-main/v3dot0'))

pcnt_chng_oilprdc = VarName1
log_econact_index = VarName2
log_rprice_oil = VarName3

y = [pcnt_chng_oilprdc, log_econact_index, log_rprice_oil]

det =1;
nlags = 12;

[VAR, VARopt] = VARmodel(y, nlags, det);


VARopt.ident = 'short';
VARopt.nsteps = 21;
[IRF, VAR] = VARir(VAR, VARopt)


VARopt.ndraws = 2000;
VARopt.pctg = 95;
VARopt.method = 'bs';

[INF, SUP, MED, BAR] = VARirband(VAR, VARopt);


horizon = 0:VARopt.nsteps-1;


subplot(3,3,1)
plot(horizon,cumsum(-INF(:,1,1)),'r:', horizon, cumsum(-SUP(:,1,1)),'r-',horizon, cumsum(-MED(:,1,1)),'b--',horizon, cumsum(-BAR(:,1,1)),'b-');
title('Oil supply shock')
ylabel('Oil production')
axis([0, 20, -25, 15])
subplot(3,3,2)
plot(horizon,-cumsum(INF(:,1,1)),'r:', horizon, -cumsum(SUP(:,1,1)),'r-',horizon, -cumsum(MED(:,1,1)),'b--',horizon, -cumsum(BAR(:,1,1)),'b-');



cumsum(-INF(:,1,1))
-cumsum(INF(:,1,1))


